# How to make a contenteditable div reversible after change made with js?

Tags: html, contenteditable, content-editor

When I delete some text in the contenteditable div in mistake, I can reverse it with <kbd>Ctrl + z</kbd>.

But after I made some change **with javascript**. I can't use <kbd>Ctrl + z</kbd> to reverse to previous change.

For example, when I add node to the selected text ,like `<p>`or `<h1>`, I could not reverse the content to previous change.
[jsfiddle.net/NfGM3/](http://jsfiddle.net/NfGM3/) 
(bad coding because I am new to `window.getSelection()`)

I use div instead of textarea because I want to add some node into the content.

So, how can I make it reversible in contenteditable div after change made with js ?

Comment: This isn't normally true: Ctrl-Z works fine in contenteditable unless you've disabled the shortcut in your key event handling. See http://jsfiddle.net/68Mwf/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about adding a keyup event handler that will keep track of the current text after every keyup. You can then trap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and revert back to the previous content if you detect that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> have been pressed.
You could potentially keep revisions in an array to support a series of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> operations.

Comment: +1, except perhaps worth handling something other than keyup (happens too often, array gets too big, too many steps to undo). IMO: keyup triggers like a 1000ms settimeout (always assigned to the same variable so there is no more than one running), with a callback to push current state into array. Result: any consecutive keystrokes typed less than 1s apart create only one history snapshot, not one per keystroke.

Comment: Good (usable) undo manager (because this is what you mean to implement) is not as simple to implement as you're thinking about it. Check e.g. CKEditor's [undoManager](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/undo/plugin.js) and note that there's plenty of places which triggers the "save snapshot" action.